# Posting Image with description using last version of Facebook SDK for Android

Tags: java, android, facebook

I want to post image from local user device with message or description, using Facebook SDK, I viewed some old solutions here in this site, but I want to use the last Facebook sdk version (3.5)
I can post image via this code but I can't add description or message

```
public void shareImageNow(Activity activity, String message,
        Bitmap bitmap, UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper) {
    List<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    images.add(bitmap);

    if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(
            activity.getApplicationContext(),
            FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.PHOTOS)) {
        // Publish the post using the Photo Share Dialog
        FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.PhotoShareDialogBuilder(
                activity).addPhotos(images).build();
        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
    } else {
        // The user doesn't have the Facebook for Android app installed.
        // You may be able to use a fallback.
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't via the Share Dialog. All messages should be user generated, and if you're using the share dialog, then there's an option in the dialog for the user to add a message or description.